# Background Image in JFrame is covering my button

Tags: java, swing

I made a JFrame in java and imported a background Image using Jlabel, but now my button is not visible nor usable, how can I move the image "behind" the button or make the background transparent.

Comment: What layout(s) are you using? Are you placing any components on a pane different than the content pane?

Comment: Provide the code you wrote in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

Without code it's impossible to say what's wrong, but likely you're adding your JLabel after your button, and the JFrame's contentPane's BorderLayout is causing one component, the JLabel, to cover the other, the JButton. A possible solution:

- Draw your image in the paintComopnent method of a JPanel.
- Add your button to this JPanel
- Add this JPanel to the JFrame (its contentPane).

---

e.g.,

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage img;

    public MyPanel(BufferedImage img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img != null) {
            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        } else {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }       
    }
}
```

Note: code not tested.

Answer (score 2):

> background Image using Jlabel, but now my button is not visible nor usable

When you use a JLabel you need to set the layout manager of the label so the button can be displayed:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(...);
label.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
JButton button = new JButton("Hello");
label.add( button );
```

Comment: And don't forget that label won't calculate its preferred size based on its child components, but based on the icon and text properties, which can produce undesirable results (clipping of content)